# Trouble accessing MSWord ActiveDocument

Tags: vba, ms-word

When I try to programmatically access a Word object model, I get an error saying no document is active.  This appears to be because I am loading the document as not visible using Word automation, and I have to keep it invisible.

How would I code the open macro so that it does nothing in this case?

`If Not ActiveDocument is Nothing Then`

didn't work.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

   If (ActiveDocument.SaveFormat = wdFormatRTF) Then
      'Do some stuff
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using ActiveDocument you could remember the document that you open (some schematic code):

```
dim word as new Word.Application
dim doc as Word.Document

doc = word.Documents.Open(fileName)
MsgBox doc.FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If Documents.Count > 0 Then
```